# Bitmap inner contours

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate inner contours of letters and trying to simulate something like inner contour of corel. I use square to sample image and calculate contours. This is what i got so far.

Only issue are square corners. Does anyone have any idea how to make green one look like the one on right or any lib that does this.

[Results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3ac.png)

```
int n = 12;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                if (IsWhite(bitmap.GetPixel(x, y))) continue;

                int minX = x - n;
                int maxX = x + n;

                if (minX < 0) minX = 0;
                if (maxX > width - 1) maxX = width - 1;

                int minY = y - n;
                int maxY = y + n;

                if (minY < 0) minY = 0;
                if (maxY > height - 1) maxY = height - 1;

                bool blackPxFound = false;
                bool redPxFound = false;

                for (int y_s = minY; y_s <= maxY; ++y_s)
                {
                    bool breakY = false;
                    for (int x_s = minX; x_s <= maxX; ++x_s)
                    {
                        Color sample = Color.White;
                        sample = bitmap.GetPixel(x_s, y_s);

                        if (IsBlack(sample)) blackPxFound = true;
                        if (IsRed(sample)) redPxFound = true;

                        if (blackPxFound && redPxFound)
                        {
                            traced.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Green);
                            breakY = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (breakY) break;

                } // end samples
               
            }
        } // end image loop

        pictureBox2.Image = traced;
```

Comment: Effectively your trace is created as if you had a 12x12 cursor drawing along with the black edge barely inside the cursor. When it turns the inside corner, this going to draw a flat edge (like setting a line to square calligraphy and corners).

Comment: I'm trying this next. 1. find horizontal and vertical edges 2. get next lines and if they are not perpendicular extend and fill the void

Comment: [This page](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_tracing) seem to cover the common algorithms - you have to deal with holes, however. You could "thicken" the boundary once found.